# Switch case Kotlin

Tags: java, switch, kotlin

Em Java utilizo o [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) em diversas situações, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Como seria isso em Kotlin, qual a declaração equivalente?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kotlin trabalha com um controle de fluxo diferente, chamado **`when`**.

Seu código, usando o `when`, poder ser assim.

Obviamente que o código poderia ser diferente, mas entendo que sua dúvida seja somente sobre o uso de `switch`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val month = 8

    val monthString = when(month) {
        1 -> "Janeiro"
        2 -> "February"
        3 -> "March"
        4 -> "April"
        5 -> "May"
        6 -> "June"
        7 -> "July"
        8 -> "August"
        9 -> "September"
        10 -> "October"
        11 -> "November"
        12 -> "December"
        else -> "Invalid month"      
    }

    println(monthString);
}
```

[Veja funcionando aqui.](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/9j5m4e5615k6nod23qe6n4je8/uac83titkrsgvgstsh840dfj40)

Comment: não preciso mais utilizar o break neste caso?

Comment: Isso, não precisa do break.

Comment: @Goiaba o `default` de java é o `else` neste cenário

Answer (score 6):

```
val monthString = when (month) {
    1 -> "January"
    2 -> "February"
    3 -> "March"
    4 -> "April"
    5 -> "May"
    6 -> "June"
    7 -> "July"
    8 -> "August"
    9 -> "September"
    10 -> "October"
    11 -> "November"
    12 -> "December"
    else -> "Invalid month"
}
```

Na verdade mesmo em Java eu faria diferente:

```
val monthString = if (month < 1 || month > 12) "Invalid month" else arrayOf("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")[month - 1]
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kiOOzp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cxkryxsu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/ArraySwitch.kt).

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode ser valer de maps para fazer isso.
Essa abordagem é bem comum em linguagens sem switch como python.

```java
val months = mapOf<Int, String>(
    1 to "January",
    2 to "February"
    3 to "March",
    4 to "April",
    5 to "May",
    6 to "June",
    7 to "July",
    8 to "August",
    9 to "September",
    10 to "October",
    11 to "November",
    12 to "December"
)
val month: String = months.get(1) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month")
```

Tudo depende do que fizer sentido pra você.